# PHP Convert a big binary file to a readable file

Tags: file-get-contents, php

I am having problems with this simple script...

```
<?php
$file = "C:\\Users\\Alejandro\\Desktop\\integers\\integers";

$file = file_get_contents($file, NULL, NULL, 0, 34359738352);

echo $file;
?>
```

It gives me always this error:

> file_get_contents(): length must be greater than or equal to zero

I am really tired, can someone help me?

EDIT:
After dividing the file in 32 parts...

The error is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1585446912 bytes exhausted (tried to al
locate 2147483648 bytes)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1585446912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocat
e 2147483648 bytes)
```

EDIT (2):

Now the deal is to convert this binary file into a list of numbers from 0 to (2^31)-1 That is why I need to read the file, so I can convert the binary digits to decimal numbers.

Comment: What does `var_dump(34359738352, 34359738352 > 0);` output on that system?

Comment: @hakre this: `float(34359738352) bool(true)`

Comment: Okay, then please report this as a bug. The error message you get by PHP is surely misleading (if not plain wrong). See Jon's answer, he hints a possible explanation (integer limit, I assume you are using a 32 bit operating system), but the error message should at least hint the type here as well or show the wrong number as well so it's clear about which value it moans.

Comment: @hakre: It's certainly *very* undesirable, but technically I believe there are grounds to shoot down a bug report on sight: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting. UB plus no warning at the same time! <3 PHP

Comment: @Jon: Many PHP functions use the float value if the integer space is not sufficient. The error message can be improved for sure anyway, and there is nothing wrong in giving feedback that can lead to improvements.

Comment: @hakre: Agree. Just saying that I don't see that happening. Somewhat like the recent conversation we had, only reversed positions. :-) BTW, it's not as straightforward as one might think: you can theoretically use float values up to the point where there is not enough precision to convert to an integer (52 bits). Altough having a file that large would be kind of a peculiarity...

Comment: In PHP normal saying is: Use 64bit system to the rescue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your file path is missing a backslash, which could be causing `file_load_contents()` to fail loading the file.

Try this instead:

```
$file = "C:\\\\Users\\Alejandro\\Desktop\\integers\\integers";
```

EDIT: Now that you can read your file, we're finding that because your file is so large, it's exceeding your memory limit and causing your script to crash.

Try buffering one piece at a time instead, so as not to exceed memory limits.  Here's a script that will read binary data, one 4-byte number at a time, which you can then process to suit your needs.

By buffering only one piece at a time, you allow PHP to use only 4 bytes at a time to store the file's contents (while it processes each piece), instead of storing the entire contents in a huge buffer and causing an overflow error.

Here you go:

```
$file = "C:\\\\Users\\Alejandro\\Desktop\\integers\\integers";

// Open the file to read binary data
$handle = @fopen($file, "rb"); 
if ($handle) { 
   while (!feof($handle)) { 
       // Read a 4-byte number
       $bin = fgets($handle, 4);
       // Process it
       processNumber($bin); 
   } 
   fclose($handle); 
}

function processNumber($bin) {
    // Print the decimal equivalent of the number
    print(bindec($bin)); 
}
```

Comment: Now the error is `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1895825408 bytes exhausted (tried to al
locate 2147483648 bytes)` which I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: You can't read a file that large at once.  Try instead iterating through it line-by-line.... will work on a solution for you.

Comment: I try dividing it into 32 parts... And nothing

Comment: Added info on how to process a file by buffering a little at a time.

Comment: I cannot read it line by line, is a binary file and I need to cnvert it to a bunch of numbers...

Comment: I see.... well, what does the data look like?  You can likely still process it in parts instead of all-at-once.

Comment: The data should be a lots of numbers from 0 to (2^31)-1 in binary. So the deal is converting it into decimal and reading all the file.

Comment: Is each number allocated a given number of bytes?  What are you doing with them when as you read them?

Comment: In theory, each number has 32 bits. And what I am doing is see what numbers are been missed in the list from 0 to (2^31)-1 . The challenge is to know which numbers are missing from that list,

Comment: Done.... now the example above will read the file in binary, 4 bytes at a time, and process each number as it reads it.

Comment: Caveat: you may want to change how it outputs the content.... printing 32GB of numbers to your screen may cause other issues.

Comment: AWESOME !! THANKS !! Brilliant Support, Steven :D

Comment: @AlejandroMorais can you add your scenario to your question please, so people can know immediately why you accepted this answer and also to make it easier to search.

Answer (score 3):

The last argument is an `int`, and apparently in your implementation of PHP `int` only has 31 bits for magnitude. The number you provide is larger than that, so this call would never work on that system.

There are also other peculiarities:

- why do you pass `NULL` for the second argument instead of `false`?
- you are saying that you want to read up to more than 2GB from that file -- is the system and PHP configuration up to doing that?

Comment: @AlejandroMorais: I would say "manually `fread` up to the desired limit in chunks less than 2GB", but I 'm not sure if reading that much into memory at once is necessary and no better solution to your problem exists.

Comment: using "false" inthe second arguments, keeps throwing the error

Comment: @AlejandroMorais: Yes, that's not supposed to fix anything. It's just that you are being a bit liberal with the arguments, which is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @AlejandroMorais: Your number needs 35 bits of magnitude to be represented as an integer, so you have to account for 35 - 31 = 4 bits. Which means up to 16 parts.

Comment: This is serious... "I AM GONNA TRY IT". Stay here for about 10 minutes while I finish writintg the code. I will then tell if I was succesful ;)

Comment: Next error: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1895825408 bytes exhausted (tried to al
locate 2147483648 bytes)` :S

Comment: @AlejandroMorais: Is it surprising that your code says "read up to 32GB of data" and PHP is not up to it? Find another way to do what you are doing. Reading that much at once is not a solution. It might be in 10 years.